# How to debug static initialiser errors in jars generated by Leiningen?

Tags: clojure

in my Clojure library `testlib`, i've got a namespace with a `:gen-class` directive that looks like this:

```
(ns com.some_long_path.NewClass
  (:import (java.util List ArrayList))
  (:gen-class
     :name com.some_long_path.NewClass
     :methods [^{:static true} [getValues [String] java.util.List]]
  )
  (:require
    [testlib.core :refer [var1 var2]]))

(defn getValues [^String]
  (java.util.ArrayList. [3 5]))
```

If i try to `import` this class inside another namespace in the `testlib` project (after invoking `compile`), i can invoke `getValues` method without errors.

However, if i `lein install`, include `testlib` in another project `jartest`, and then use it in a test namespace below

```
(ns jartest.core
  (:import [com.some_long_path NewClass]))

(NewClass.)
(NewClass/getValues "some string")
```

invoking `NewClass` constructor gives an exception

```
CompilerException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.some_long_path.NewClass
```

and `getValues` as a consequence gives

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'com.some_long_path.NewClass/getValues
```

However, if i remove the `require`s from `NewClass` namespace definition above, the code works even in another library. So the problem is caused by some missing dependencies, although i've made sure that all dependencies of `testlib` are also included in `jartest`, and that `testlib.core` namespace is AOT-compiled.

Also, i've tried decompiling generated `com.some_long_path.NewClass` class file, and there is a static initializer block that looks like this:

```
static
{
  Util.loadWithClass("/com/some_long_path/NewClass", NewClass.class);
}
```

Most probably the above-mentioned error is thrown from within `loadWithClass`. But how do i find out what exactly is wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I was able to figure out what was wrong in the namespace i was requiring through a binary search for errors (commenting out code until things worked again). It turned out that some files were `slurp`ed from `resources` folder in `testlib`, but they were not present in `jartest` project. Changing the code to use `clojure.java.io/resource` fixed the problem. However, the question still stands - how to find out exactly what was the problem, without resorting to brute force methods?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the obligatory answer- there isnt a better way, without understanding the dependency tree more deeply, which often can only be done by commenting stuff out and seeing what now works. That has been my experience with java classloading from clojure and using gen-class.

Heres hoping this isnt the highest voted answer.